# Android AsyncHttpClient: how to POST a custom Object(model)?

Tags: android, android-async-http

I have a `User` model and I want to POST it via AsyncHttpClient. Documentation says I have to add each parameter manually:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
 params.put("username", user.name);
 params.put("password", user.password);
 ...
```

Am I really required to do that each time when I need to POST a model? What if my model has 100 fields? Is there a quick way to do it this way:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("user", user);
```

- yes I've seen that it is possible if `user` is `Map` but what if `user` is custom `Object` (model)? I'm new to Android so I don't know if there is an easy way to convert an `Object` into a `Map`?

Comment: Obviously, you need to write such a conversion yourself: New a HashMap, and fill in the fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is up to you how you want to send the data.

One option is to use JSON with Google's [Gson library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Then you can do for example:

```
params.put("user", new Gson().toJson(user));
```

`toJson()` converts your object into a JSON string which you will then need to deserialize on the server. [Example](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples)